# get list of data for mutiple id in one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

i have two entities with name of "Area" and "Estate" relationship

per area has many estates(sale estates) and per estate has one area (one to many)

i want to get list of estates for mutiple area

this is my code :

```
var estates = _unitOfWork.Set<Sale>().AsQueryable();
IQueryable<Sale> filteredEstates = estates.Where(e => e.Status == 1);

if (requestBuy.Areas.Count > 0)
{
    filteredEstates = requestBuy.Areas.SelectMany(e => e.Sales).AsQueryable();
    //var filteredEstatesNew = new List<Sale>();
    //foreach (var area in requestBuy.Areas)
    //{
    //    filteredEstatesNew.AddRange(area.Sales.ToList());
    //}
    //filteredEstates = filteredEstatesNew.AsQueryable();
    //filteredEstates = filteredEstates.Where(e => e.Status == 1);
}
```

i think my way is wrong! so help me how to do that?!

Comment: What's wrong with SelectMany?

Comment: because after this code i have other filters on filteredStates!

Comment: What is `filteredStates`?

Comment: just a queryable variable for filtering estates on many items which is the areas just one of this filters! adter this code i'm filter the estates based on other filters like name , locations and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you have implemented your unit of work and repositories, but if you have one to many relationship (area to estates) in Entity Framework and you want to get filtered estates, then you should use SelectMany like this:

```
var estates = areas.Where(a => a.Foo == Bar) // area filter
                   .SelectMany(a => a.Estates)
                   .Where(e => e.Status == 1); // estate filter
```

Or with query syntax

```
var estates = from a in areas
              where a.Foo == Bar  // area filter
              from e in a.Estates // SelectMany
              where e.Status == 1 // estate filter
              select e;
```

Comment: is this query send request to database and get the data? or after the ToList() called that happens?! i have other filters on estates after this query and i want all the queries sent to database just once!

Comment: @amir-yeketaz request to database will occur only when you will execute query. So, this query definition does not send request to database. It will be sent when you will call ToList or when you will try to enumerate results. Following operators will execute query: ToList, ToDictionary, GetEnumerator, Count, Sum, Max, First, Single etc. See [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx) for all such operators